# Temperature too high in kinetic gas theory experiment with steel balls

Tags: statistical-mechanics, experimental-physics, kinetic-theory

I'm doing a small experiment about kinetic gas theory where I have to check if the density of my gas corresponds to the barometric formula. My experimental setup is like this one [Experimental setup](https://www.nikhef.nl/%7Eh73/kn1c/praktikum/phywe/LEP/Experim/1_4_07.pdf) where I got my gas density with a photoelectric detector. When I take logarithms and fit it to a linear regression all, it fits perfectly.
My problem is when I try to go a little further and get the average gas temperature with the value of the slope . Where I get temperatures on the order of $10^{21}K$ which is too high. I believe that the problem may be that in order to deduce the barometric formula we have used the following relation:
\begin{equation}
PV=nN_Ak_BT=Nk_BT
\end{equation}
where we have taken the number of moles times the avogadro number as our number of balls (which in my case were 400) so for my problem the boltzmann's constant must be normalized. As the avogadro number is of the order of $10^{23}$ and the number of balls is $10^2$ the Boltzmann constant should be divided by $10^{21}$ obtaining now too low temperatures since they would be over 5K far from the ideal gas.
Does anyone know what can happen here?